# How to adjust the selector used in JS to target only the one that was clicked on?

Tags: javascript

I have a js question that has me somewhat confused.

What I have is a plugin that allows following. It's working quite well, except for one thing in particular. When there are a couple of follow links on the same page it triggers all of them. While the result is what is desired, meaning that only the person clicked gets the follow, all the links appear to trigger. I'm assuming it has something to do with $this, but I'm not sure, and don't know where to try and fix it. This is the js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /*******************************
    follow / unfollow a user
    *******************************/
    $( '.follow-links a' ).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);

        if( pwuf_vars.logged_in != 'undefined' && pwuf_vars.logged_in != 'true' ) {
            alert( pwuf_vars.login_required );
            return;
        }

        var data      = {
            action:    $this.hasClass('follow') ? 'follow' : 'unfollow',
            user_id:   $this.data('user-id'),
            follow_id: $this.data('follow-id'),
            nonce:     pwuf_vars.nonce
        };

        $('img.pwuf-ajax').show();

        $.post( pwuf_vars.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            if( $.response == 'success' ) {
                $('.follow-links a').toggle();
            } else {
                alert( pwuf_vars.processing_error );
            }
            $('img.pwuf-ajax').hide();
        } );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.follow-links a').toggle();` should be `$this.toggle();`.

Comment: I gave that a try and it gives a response that something went wrong when I try to follow or unfollow

Comment: Well yes, `$.response == 'success'` should probably be `response == 'success'`.

Comment: That did the trick. :) The only thing that I noticed was that the link that should appear, following when followed, and follow when unfollowed disappear. But they come back again on refresh.

Comment: On refresh? You mean page refresh? You need to handle that when generating the page, check if and who the current user follows and output the HTML with the proper CSS attached.

Comment: That's correct. When I follow someone the link that should appear doesnt. But if I click on the refresh button in the browser the link that should have appeared is now there. Eg. It should have gone from follow to following, but it vanished like a politician under pressure. Click refresh in the browser and it comes back how it should be as following. It still follows or unfollows correctly. Just the link that is supposed to appear doesn't until you refresh the page

Comment: OK, so your question evolved I see as we go along with fixing your code. Instead of `$this.toggle()` use something like `$this.toggleClass('follow').toggleClass('unfollow')`.